# How insert labels to the ggplot plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot, where dashed red lines separated based on the highest value of `week_hour` for specific `weekday2` (`week_hour_dummy` was created for dashed line).
I want that between two red dashed lines was an entry that corresponds to `weekday2`
An approximate view of the new plot is attached below. (if not possible to do so, is it possible to add `weekday2` to X-axis instead?)

```
q3<-structure(list(week_hour = 1:168, week_hour_dummy = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 48, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 72, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 96, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 144, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 168), over_supply = c(15.6, 17.2, 13, 11.6, 9.8, 13.2, 16.8, 
15.8, 13.8, 12.8, 26.4, 42.2, 40.8, 38, 41.2, 48.2, 47.2, 42.4, 
18.4, 35.4, 47.2, 42, 26.6, 24.8, 19.4, 21.2, 16.2, 16.6, 16.8, 
16.2, 21.8, 23.4, 13, 13, 36.2, 42.2, 41, 38.4, 39.6, 47, 43.2, 
42.4, 21.8, 23.8, 40.2, 34.6, 23.8, 15, 15.8, 23, 22.4, 15.8, 
15.6, 18.5, 21.4, 24.4, 18.8, 15.4, 46.8, 53.4, 43.6, 42.4, 48.6, 
48, 57, 19.2, 14.8, 23.2, 39.2, 43.8, 28, 13, 15.4, 28.6, 16.6, 
15.6, 18.4, 20.2, 25, 22.8, 14.2, 10.8, 31.4, 37.6, 37.2, 32, 
37.4, 40.4, 40.4, 23, 8.6, 11, 23.2, 33, 26.2, 8.2, 7, 22.4, 
20, 12, 15.4, 18.8, 22.6, 20.4, 10.2, 4.4, 21.2, 28, 30.6, 29.4, 
26, 22.8, 31.4, 20.4, 4.8, 18.6, 27.2, 35, 48.8, 32.6, 20.6, 
19.8, 12.6, 7.4, 11, 23.8, 25.2, 21.4, 20.4, 20.2, 17.6, 18, 
20.2, 30.4, 22.6, 25.8, 31.8, 35.6, 43, 37, 36.8, 44, 47.4, 33.2, 
17, 16.8, 22.6, 15.8, 15, 23, 23.8, 21.8, 17.4, 17.4, 21.2, 18.2, 
11, 14.6, 26.6, 31, 27.4, 29.4, 27.4, 29.6, 33, 34.8, 16, 17.4
), weekday2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("E", 
"T", "K", "N", "R", "L", "P"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-168L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ggplot(data=q3) +
  geom_line(aes(x=week_hour  , y=over_supply ,group=1,fill="Over-supply"),lwd=1,col="blue")+
  geom_vline(data = subset(q3, !(week_hour_dummy == 0)), # filter data source
             aes(xintercept = week_hour ),
             size = 1, colour = "red", linetype="dashed")
```

[image]

Comment: Have you seen these articles? http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-texts-add-text-annotations-to-a-graph-in-r-software and http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-add-straight-lines-to-a-plot-horizontal-vertical-and-regression-lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:

Add `geom_text()` to create the label working with a version of your data filtered on the mid point between each 24 hour period; you can adjust label appearance and location arguments to suit your requirements.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

  
ggplot(q3) +
  geom_line(aes(x = week_hour, y = over_supply),lwd = 1, col = "blue")+
  geom_text(data = filter(q3, week_hour %% 24 == 12),
            aes(x = week_hour, y = Inf, label = weekday2),
            colour = "red",
            size = 10,
            vjust = 1.2)+
  geom_vline(data = subset(q3, !(week_hour_dummy == 0)), # filter data source
             aes(xintercept = week_hour ),
             size = 1, colour = "red", linetype="dashed")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>